# Selecting SAS column by the character string within a row observation

Tags: sas

I have a table(A) with rows that have character strings that should match column names. I'm trying to match the name within the row observation with the corresponding column of the table A and check the values within that column and give a T/F flag.

for example if the row observation is 'A-3', i can go into the 'A-3' column and check that corresponding row for a value.

Answer (score 2):

Use VVALUEX() as long as you're ok with everything coming back as characters.
[Link to VVALUEX documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n1x70jnnpttwy0n1gf5rvuivgyry.htm&locale=en)

A-3 isn't a valid SAS variable name, but assuming it is you'd refer to it as 'A-3'n.

```
   data want;
      set have;
      x = vvaluex('A-3'n);
      x1 = vvaluex(A_3);    
   run;
```