# In the Data step of SAS, how can I get value of a Column with Column's name represented as a String?

Tags: sas

In the Data Step of SAS, you get value of a Column by directly using its name, for example, like this,

```
name = col1;
```

But for some reason, I want to get value of a column where column is represented by a string. For example, like this,

```
name = get_value_of_column(cats("col", i))
```

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: Homework question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64486690/selecting-sas-column-by-the-character-string-within-a-row-observation

Comment: Haha no, its because I have columns with names like _Col1_, _Col2_, and want to get their value by index.

Comment: An array or using VVALUEX gets you there then. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/sas-arrays/

Comment: Yes, VVALUEX did the trick. Arrays don't apply because these columns already exist and generated automatically by a process.

Comment: Arrays would work fine - it doesn't matter if the variables exist prior or not. An added benefit is an array will return the same variable type, VVALUEX always returns a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DATA Step functions `VVALUE` and `VVALUEX` will return the **formatted** value of a variable.

- `VVALUE(<variable-name>)` static, a step compilation time interaction
- `VVALUEX(<expression>)` dynamic, a runtime expression resolving to a variable name

The actual value of the variable can be dynamically obtained via a _*type*_ array scan

**Array Scan**

```
data have;
input name $ x y z (s t u) ($) date: yymmdd10.;
format s t u $upcase. date yymmdd10.;
datalines;
x 1 2 3 a b c          2020-10-01
y 2 3 4 b c d          2020-10-02
z 3 4 5 c d e          2020-10-03
s 4 5 6 hi ho silver   2020-10-04
t 5 6 7 aa bb cc       2020-10-05
u 6 7 8 -- ** !!       2020-10-06
date 7 8 9 ppp qqq rrr 2020-10-07
;

data want;
  set have;

  length u_vvalue name_vvaluex $20.;

  u_vvalue = vvalue(u);
  name_vvaluex = vvaluex(name);

  array nums _numeric_;
  array chars _character_;

  /* NOTE:
   * variable based arrays cause automatic variable _i_ to be in the PDV
   * and _i_ will be automatically dropped from output data sets
   */
  do _i_ = 1 to dim(nums);
    if upcase(name) = upcase(vname(nums(_i_))) then do;
      name_numeric_raw = nums(_i_);
      leave;
    end;
  end;
  do _i_ = 1 to dim(chars);
    if upcase(name) = upcase(vname(chars(_i_))) then do;
      name_character_raw = chars(_i_);
      leave;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

If you perform an 'excessive' amount of dynamic value lookup in your DATA Step a transposition could possibly lead to simpler processing.